# jQuery click more than once

Tags: jquery

I have started teaching myself jQuery and I was wondering how you can add multiple click functions where something different happens with each click.

Heres an example of what i am trying to do :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#color").click( function() {
$("#change_me").css("color", "purple");
$("#change_me").css("color", "black");
});//end color
});//end doc ready
```

I originally only had the "purple" line so when I clicked on the text it changed purple. I then added the "black" line (to return it to the default colour) but it now bypasses the purple state.

I tried adding another click function but that didn't work

Comment: It's not bypassing the purple line. It's executing the purple line, then executing the black line. It just happens so fast you don't see it. If you want it to alternate colors on each click, you need to add the logic to do so. Like set a flag and change it on each click. Or look into a function like http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: are you saying you want it turn purple on the first click, then turn black the on second click? What about the third etc?

Comment: For it to work the way you want, you would need to check the current colour of the line before applying a new colour. So if it was currently purple, you change it to black. Likewise if it's black, you change it to purple

Comment: @markpsmith - that sounds like what I want to do. How do I go about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery `toggleClass` for that, create a class with the color you want after click and on click it will add/remove the class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#color").click( function() {
$("#change_me").toggleClass("purple");
//$("#change_me").css("color", "black");
});//end color
});//end
```

```css
.purple{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color">
<p id="change_me">
Click on the text to change its color
</p>
</div>
```

if you want to change between more than 2 colors you can do it like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change_me").toggle(
        function(){$("#change_me").css({"color": "purple"});},
        function(){$("#change_me").css({"color": "black"});},
        function(){$("#change_me").css({"color": "green"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color">
<p id="change_me">
Click on the text to change its color
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats perfect Ram Segev. Thanks very much